# Create a generic context with a state from parent component using TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-context

I set a state in my page component `formData` and I would like to create a context in my form component to use it in each form child component. Without TS everything works perfectly. But with TS, it tell me on `setFormData`, `username` and `email` does not exist on type `IFormValues`.

I would like to find a tips to say "hey Form component data type is ..." and stay generic in my `Form` component.

**My page**

```
const RegisterPage: NextPage = () => {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        username: '',
        email: '',
    })
    return (
        <Form state={[formData, setFormData]} name="mySuperForm">...</Form>
    )
}
```

**My component**

```
interface IFormValues {
    [key: string]: string | number
}

interface IFormProps extends FormHTMLAttributes<Element> {
    state: [IFormValues, Dispatch<SetStateAction<IFormValues>>]
    name: string
}

interface IFormContext {
    values: IFormValues
    setValues: Dispatch<SetStateAction<IFormValues>>
    name: string
}

const FormContext = createContext<Partial<IFormContext>>({})

const Form: FC<IFormProps> = (props) => {
    const cleanProps = {...props, state: undefined}
    return (
        <FormContext.Provider value={{
            values: props.state[0], 
            setValues: props.state[1],
            name: props.name
        }}>
            <form {...cleanProps} />
        </FormContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

If I use that:

```
interface IFormValues {
    username: string
    email: string
}
```

everything works

Answer (score 0):

You have to properly type the `useState` in the `RegisterPage` component the same way you do for the `Form` props.

```js
import type { IFormValues } from "../components/Form";

const RegisterPage: NextPage = () => {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState<IFormValues>({
        username: '',
        email: '',
    })
    return (
        <Form state={[formData, setFormData]} name="some-name">...</Form>
    )
}
```

Note that you also have to pass a `name` prop to `Form` as that's a required prop as well. TypeScript will complain otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
It's was my first idea but it doesn't work and about name it was just a rewriting mistake. I think the best solution is extends my state from `IFormValues` and say to my `IFormProps` you need to extends from `IFormValues` but i didn't find extend from or an like "implement"  in TS

Comment: Can you clarify what's not working with the above solution? In my solution `IFormValues` is defined as `interface IFormValues { [key: string]: string | number }` like in your code.

Comment: Yes, it's true, it break my page component typing, but work with Form component
```The argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to the parameter of type 'string'.``` Thats the reason why i need to find an other solution or iterate my state on each child component

Comment: Which line in your page component is throwing that TypeScript error? Both in the code you provided, and my example, `string` type is being assigned to `string | number` type, not the other way around.

Comment: Each row expecting to receive a string 
```setEmailValidity(REGEX.email.test(formData.email))```

Comment: My problem is why force my state which has a predictable type for the benefit of a child component which must have a type adaptable to the state it receives

Comment: It looks like the code you provided isn't the full picture. Without more details about the remaining code, I'd suggest you either narrow down the value to the expected type, or cast it to the expected type.